# Execute command with arguments and a pipe

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to execute the command below in a PowerShell script

```
C:\PATH TO GPG\gpg.exe --output OUTPUTFILE.csv --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt C:\PATH TO INPUT\INPUTFILE.txt < C:\PATH TO PASS\Passphrase.txt
```

When I assign various sections of the command to variables and then combine them in a command varible and try and execute it as follows:

```
$decryptCommand = "${gpg} --output ${dateStamp}.csv --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt ${fileName} < ${passphraseFile}"
&$decryptCommand
```

I receive the following error:

```
The term 'XXXX' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I have tried to surround various parts of the command in single and double quotes but nothing I've tried seems to work.

Is there something extra I should be doing to execute this command from a PowerShell script?

Comment: Print the decrypt command to screen. Does it work if you copy-paste it to a Powershell session?  In addition, what's the `'XXXX'` part of the error message anyway? A literal string `'XXXX'` or a bit of censored text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with you script. First, you don't need to surround variable with `{}`, secon - you have to pass parameters seperately, like this:

```
&$gpg --output $dateStamp.csv --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt $fileName < $passphraseFile
```

The only thing I'm not sure about is `<` symbol. It might be the case that you will need to escape it with `'`

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. Instead of using the `<` I was able to make it another parameter and execute one long command. Thanks again.